# Counting push notifications on iOS (deal with cancel from notif center)

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications, push-notification, uiapplication

I'm trying to understand on how to deal with a particular use case with push notifications.

Let's suppose that I have 4 push notifications in the notification center waiting for an interaction, the server keeps track of the badge number. The user picks up one, in the `-application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:` I decrement the badge and communicate to the server the notification back to make it decrements its "badge" number and mark the notification as read.Everything works fine.
I'm not able to deal with that case. Let's say that the user deletes from the notification center one notification and then opens the app by tapping on another, I will have an incorrect badge number on both server and app, since deleting a notification it doesn't seem to affect the badge number.
Is there a way to understand which remote notification has been removed?
It seem that for a more fine grained control is better to use a mix of silent push and remote notification.

Comment: Can you give an example how you are using push notifications? Badge can't reflect number of notifications in notif. centre, because notifications are not guaranteed to be delivered.

Comment: Your badge number should be related to actions that the user takes in your app, regardless of how they Launched your app

Comment: Hi @VojtechVrbka The server keeps track of the "badge" number, that means that if a notification is not delivered the feedback server will return a fault  and the server will not increment its badge count for the next notification to be delivered

Comment: But you don't know if a notification wasn't delivered.

Comment: @Paulw11 if a notification wasn't delivered would the feedback notification server tell me that? Did I misunderstood the documentation? "The Apple Push Notification service includes a feedback service to give you information about failed remote notifications"

Comment: The feedback server tells you if a notification wasn't delivered because the device token is invalid(e.g. The app has been uninstalled) but not if there was simply a network problem or the device was turned off for too long.  I haven't got time right now, but if you read through that same guide you will see where it describes that push notifications are not guaranteed or reliable delivery and you should be prepared to handle silent failure

Comment: @Paulw11 thanks for the clarification it does make sense. At this point I'm wondering how third party services provides means to do that for instance PARSE http://blog.parse.com/announcements/badge-management-for-ios/

Comment: Parse tracks the current badge number for each device and allows you to specify `increment` to have it craft the right payloads for the push to each device but you are responsible for clearing all of the badges.  Let's say the badge is currently 10 and you send a push which would make it 11 but that gets lost. When you send the next increment push it will go to 12 and the device will show that. When you launch your app you either reset the badge to 0 or you update it based on actions the user takes in the app such as reading a message.

Comment: The other thing you should do when your app launches is check with your back end what actions etc are outstanding in case pushes were lost.